# Turning demo mode on and off on a Kobo

Tags: kobo

Demo mode is currently on on my Kobo. I would like to turn it off. How can I turn on and off demo mode on a Kobo eReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn demo mode on by typing: `demo mode on` into the search box.

You can turn demo mode off by typing: `demo mode off` into the search box.